# MimeKit message creation breaking application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mailkit

I am using the Mimekit to generate and send emails with this code

```
                        var message = new MimeMessage();
                        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Oliver Parker", "oliverxparker@gmail.com"));
                        string username = selectedFriend.username;
                        var email = selectedFriend.email;
                        var mailSender = MailboxAddress.Parse(email);
                        message.To.Add(mailSender);
                        message.Subject = "Registration successful";
```

This code used to work fine without any errors but now when I hit that first line that calls new MimeMessage I just get a screen saying my application has crashed. I have recently updated to Oreo 8/Oxygen OS 5.0.3 so I am unsure if MimeKit is just incompatible with this version of Android. Anyone have any idea what could of changed with the NuGet package to break this? Any alternatives to sending emails with xamarin.android?

Comment: What is the Exception? Check `logcat` if needed...

Comment: You need to upgrade your Xamarin.Android - the version you have has a bug in the runtime that crashes when MimeKit initializes itself (due to the use of `Encoding.GetEncoding()`).